# what does "Error running C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)" mean?

Tags: r, sweave

I am trying to run this code in Rsweave

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\bfseries Unemployment in India:January-April 2016:India}
\rfoot{\textit{June 2016}}
\lfoot{BSE-CMIE}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\section{India}

<<fig = TRUE , echo = FALSE>>=


unemp_monthly= read.csv("C:/Users/user/Downloads/ue_msamplefile_4.txt", sep= "|", header= T)
library(survey)
unemp_monthly$LABOUR_FORCE <- ifelse(unemp_monthly$EMPLOYMENT_STATUS == "Employed" | unemp_monthly$EMPLOYMENT_STATUS == "Unemployed, willing and looking for a job", 1 , 0)
unemp_monthly$UNEMPLOYED <- ifelse(unemp_monthly$EMPLOYMENT_STATUS == "Unemployed, willing and looking for a job" , 1 , 0)
options(survey.lonely.psu= "adjust")
mem_nstrat= svydesign(id= ~HR + TOWN_VILLAGE + HH_ID, strata= ~STRATA, fpc= ~FPC_REGION_HR_STATE_TOTAL + FPC_REGION_TV_HR_TOTAL + FPC_REGION_HH_TV, weight= ~MEM_WEIGHT_GE15_STATE_REGTYPE_SAMPLE, data= unemp_monthly, nest= T)
unemp_rate_monthly= svyby(~UNEMPLOYED, by= ~COUNTRY, denominator= ~LABOUR_FORCE, design= mem_nstrat, svyratio)
unemp_rate_monthly_region_type= svyby(~UNEMPLOYED, by= ~REGION_TYPE, denominator= ~LABOUR_FORCE, design= mem_nstrat, svyratio)
print(unemp_rate_monthly_region_type)
print(unemp_rate_monthly)


@



\end{document}
```

But when I run this code this error pops out

```
Writing to file header_footer.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : keep.source term verbatim pdf  (header_footer.Rnw:16)
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: survival

Attaching package: 'survey'

The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':

    dotchart


You can now run (pdf)latex on 'header_footer.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on header_footer.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)
```

Please help.

Comment: Check this out: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040064/knitr-compile-problems-with-rstudio-windows). It may contain some hints. Is it ?

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I'm getting the same error on Windows 10 with RStudio version 1.2.5019 and MiKTeX 2.9. My Linux setup is working without issue.