# Error running C:/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

Tags: miktex, rstudio

I'm using latex in rstudio and when I try to compile pdf I get this mensage: Error running C:/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

How can I solve this problem? I'm desperate, I'm trying to solve it for 3 days and I can't. Please, someone help me.

Comment: Hi, welcomme. Which version of MikTeX do you use? What is your operating system? Is this your first installation? Did you try to uninstall MiKtEX and reinstall it with the latest version?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Hm, version 1.9 (if it ever exists, I do not know) seems to be heavy outdated, the current version of MikTeX is 2.9.  Can you please the **first line** of your `*.log` file to your question? It shows us used TeX Distribution and version number ...

Comment: Welcome! I had a similar challenge and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158374/miktex-failing-when-knitting-rmarkdown-document) on SO to the same question brought the solution. I suggest you try it out. Good luck.

Comment: @AndréC, I'm using the miktex 2.9 version. I use windows 10. Yes, I uninstalled and reinstalled three times, always with the lates version.

Comment: @Mensch, the first line of *.log file is this: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.10)  13 AUG 2019 14:45

Comment: Well, and you also delete all old versions of r, rmarkdown, knitr and rstudio? Perhaps one of them keeps a link to an outdated miktex path? Did you check that?

Comment: During installation, it is necessary to disable all antivirus software and leave only the Windows 10 antivirus software active.

Comment: @Mensch, I didn't check this. I only deleted old versions of R and Rstudio. I will uninstall all of them (r, rmarkdown, knitr and rstudio) and tomorrow I will post here the results. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréC, I didn't know this. I will uninstall r, rstudio, knitr and rmarkdown and during the process for install them again I will disable all antivirus software, except windows 10 antivirus. Tomorrow I will post here the result. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any news for us?

Comment: Hey @Mensch, I uninstalled R, Rstudio, knitr and rmarkdown. And I installed all them again with the antivirus software disabled. But when I tried to compile the pdf I get the same problem: Running pdflatex.exe on test.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/ALEXAN~1/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

Comment: @Mensch, it is interesting the fact that my new rstudio opened all the script files that was open in the old rstudio (that I had uninstaled). Is this normal?

Comment: @AndréC, I installed miktex, r and rstudio with the ativirus software disabled, but I get the same problem: Running pdflatex.exe on test.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/ALEXAN~1/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)

Comment: I do not know rstudio, I can not help you with that. I am an MiKTeX user and I know that version MiKTeX 1.9 is **absolutly outdated**. So you have to check your computer where this old version is hidden. perhaps you need to do the installation in a special order to omit that rstudio or whatelse software is installing an old MiKTeX version. Please ask the support of rstudio or knitr or what else you use for running r for this issue. As long as you have `C:/Users/ALEXAN~1/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/` active you will **not get rid of that error!** Check the path variable for wrong path ...

Comment: @alexandre Did you test MikTeX before installing the other software? Does it work on its own without the others?

Comment: Crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447104/error-running-c-miktex1-9-miktex-bin-x64-pdflatex-exe-exit-code-1

Comment: Did you saw question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328183/what-does-error-running-c-users-user-appdata-local-programs-miktex1-9-miktex ?